# VPS server htop shows 4 bars in 100% with yellow!

Tags: 20.04, vps, htop

what is the yellow color means!?

is it DDos attack or something else !?

its VPS with Ubuntu 20.04 64bit from Hostinger with Cpanel installed.

all websites are down
[image]

Comment: Looks like the `mysqld` has possibly crashed or forked.  Either way, it will have to be restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Since it depends on the design set, I recommend taking a look at the help. You can open the help with F1.
At the top of the Help page, you can see a reference to the colour of the bars.